# PL/PgSQL creating a conditional trigger on insert

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, conditional-statements

I'm working on my first ever Trigger. When I'm doing an INSERT on table I want to conditionaly remove rows from other table.

Here is a trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clear_seen_by()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
    BEGIN
         IF (OLD.popup = '1') THEN
              DELETE FROM news_seen_by;
            END IF;

        RETURN NULL;
    END;
   $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Invoked by:

```
  CREATE TRIGGER clear_seen_by
  AFTER INSERT
  ON news
  FOR EACH STATEMENT
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE clear_seen_by();
```

As an error I see that NEW or OLD (if I motify the trigger) is not declared/unknown. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an INSERT statement you do not have an `OLD` record defined.

You should use `NEW.popup` instead, and also declare the trigger to be `FOR EACH ROW`.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clear_seen_by() RETURNS trigger AS
  $BODY$
    BEGIN
      IF (NEW.popup = '1') THEN
        DELETE FROM news_seen_by;
      END IF;

      RETURN NULL;
    END;
  $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE COST 100;


  CREATE TRIGGER
    clear_seen_by
  AFTER INSERT ON
    news
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
    clear_seen_by();
```

Comment: No. I tried both - the same error with OLD and NEW: SQLSTATE[55000]: Object not in prerequisite state: 7 ~the structore of record NEW/OLD is unknown yet

Comment: Ah, then define the trigger to be `FOR EACH ROW`.

Answer (score 1):

You declare a trigger `FOR EACH STATEMENT`. Maybe you need `FOR EACH ROW`?

`FOR EACH STATEMENT` triggers do not have `NEW` and `OLD`.